# Procedure or function has too many arguments specified asp.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net, stored-procedures

Through this stored procedure I'm trying to insert dynamically created data Table which is bind to Grid View. When i have one row in data Table for insert, it's ok, the row is inserted, but when i have more rows in data Table for insert then it give me an error:

Procedure or function insertMarkica has too many arguments specified.

Also the parameter @MarkicaID i'm declaring in stored procedure which is incremented for one when is add new row.I think that here is the problem, when add one row the parameter @Mar is incremented, but for the rest probably is not.Please help me to solve this issue.

```
       ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertMarkica]
@FirmaID    tinyint,
 @Godina    smallint,
 @MarkicaID     int,
 @Datum     datetime,
 @Masa  smallint,



@Kasa tinyint
AS
   BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @Mar int

   Select @Mar = ISNULL(MAX(MarkicaID)+1,1)
    FROM Markici
      WHERE FirmaID = @FirmaID And Godina = @Godina and kasaid=@Kasa

     INSERT INTO Markici ( FirmaID, Godina, KasaID, Masa, MarkicaID,Datum)                
     VALUES (@FirmaID, @Godina,@Kasa,  @Masa, @Mar,@Datum)

    Select Markica = @Mar
   END
```

Here is the code for parameters for data Table

```
     dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["Markici"];



            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertMarkica",conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "InsertMarkica";
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtCurrentTable.Rows)
            {

                //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirmaID", dr["FirmaID"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Godina", dr["Godina"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kasa", dr["KasaID"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Masa", dr["Masa"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MarkicaID", dr["MarkicaID"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datum", dr["Datum"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VrabotenID", dr["VrabotenID"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Smena", dr["Smena"]);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
            }
```

// method form creating dataColumns:

```
private void AddDefaultFirstRecord()
    {

        //creating DataTable  
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr;
        dt.TableName = "Markici";
        //creating columns for DataTable  
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FirmaID", typeof(System.Int32)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Godina", typeof(System.Int32)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("KasaID", typeof(System.Int32)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MarkicaID", typeof(System.Int64)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Datum", typeof(System.DateTime)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Masa", typeof(System.Int32)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("VrabotenID", typeof(System.Int32)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Artikal", typeof(System.String)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Cena1", typeof(System.String)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Kolicina", typeof(System.Decimal)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Smena", typeof(System.Int32)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("VkIznos", typeof(System.Decimal)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("VkDanok", typeof(System.Decimal)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SysDatum", typeof(System.DateTime)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Vid", typeof(System.String)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("EdMera", typeof(System.String)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ArtikalID", typeof(System.String)));
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        ViewState["Markici"] = dt;

        GridView2.DataSource = dt;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: The stored proc access less parameters than what you passing in the code.

Comment: removed, but it give me the same error.Work only when add just one row

Comment: Before you add parameters, you need to call cmd.Parameters.Clear(); inside the loop

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helps me, now i can insert more than one row!.

Answer (score 0):

Remove @ sing in below line:

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirmaID", dr["FirmaID"]);`

and all the others you are adding more parameters than the stored procedure needs.
and check the parameters required by Stored procedure. you are sending more parameters than needed

Comment: removed, but it give me the same error.Work only when add just one row in dataTable.

Answer (score 0):

You have define 6 params in your stored procedure and you are providing it 8 params in your code..

remove the last two params

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertMarkica]
@FirmaID    tinyint,
@Godina    smallint,
@MarkicaID     int,
@Datum     datetime,
@Masa  smallint,
@Kasa tinyint

AS
   BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @Mar int

   Select @Mar = ISNULL(MAX(MarkicaID)+1,1)
    FROM Markici
      WHERE FirmaID = @FirmaID And Godina = @Godina and kasaid=@Kasa

     INSERT INTO Markici ( FirmaID, Godina, KasaID, Masa, MarkicaID,Datum)                
     VALUES (@FirmaID, @Godina,@Kasa,  @Masa, @Mar,@Datum)

    Select Markica = @Mar
END
```

### Code Behind

```
dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["Markici"];



SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertMarkica",conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "InsertMarkica";
foreach (DataRow dr in dtCurrentTable.Rows)
{

    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirmaID", dr["FirmaID"]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Godina", dr["Godina"]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kasa", dr["KasaID"]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Masa", dr["Masa"]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MarkicaID", dr["MarkicaID"]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datum", dr["Datum"]);
```

> extra params that are not decalred in stored procedure (remove both)

```
    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VrabotenID", dr["VrabotenID"]); 
    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Smena", dr["Smena"]);


    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
}
```

or else define 2 params and insert it in  [dbo].[insertMarkica] stored procedure and it will not gives you the error again.

**Edited:**
You also need to clear your parameters every time the loop executes with `cmd.Parameters.Clear();` inside the loop before assigning parameters.

Make sure you are giving the right amount of params that are required by the stored procedure in order to avoid any trouble.

Comment: removed, but it give me the same error.Work only when add just one row of dataTable

Comment: Make sure you are giving all the values in a correct format and when you are adding more then 1 line, no param should be null in order to work. If there is any value that may be null, then you will need to declare a nullable param

Comment: As you have dynamic data, but you need to make sure that no parameter is going null otherwise it won't work.

What values do you have in your grid that you needs to insert in db?

Comment: i've edited question, put there method for creating columns, values are labels converted in appropriate format like columns.

Answer (score 0):

remove these two lines:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VrabotenID", dr["VrabotenID"]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Smena", dr["Smena"]);
```

and also in store procedure you have defined parameter as  `@MarkicaID int`, so in insert command pass `@MarkicaID` insted of `@Mar`

Comment: removed, but it give me the same error.Work only when add just one row

Comment: It happens if there is any null value.first clear the all parameter value by  calling cmd.Parameters.Clear();